# How to use the same template with two CBVs in django?

Tags: django, templates

I have two CBVs in django

```
class StudentUpdateView(UpdateView):
model = Student
template_name = "students/students_edit.html"
form_class = StudentUpdateForm

def get_success_url(self):
    return u'%s?status_message=Студент успішно збережений ' % reverse('home')

def post(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
    if request.POST.get('cancel_button'):
        messages.info(self.request, "Edit canceled")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            u'%s?status_message=Редагування відмінено'
            % reverse('home'))
    else:
        messages.success(self.request, u"Студент змінений") 
        return super(StudentUpdateView, self).post(
            request,*arg, **kwargs)
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(StudentUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return context
```

Another one is for the same model but CreateView. I want to use the same template for this two views, and there are some parts in template i want to be dynamic.

{% block meta_title %}Редагувати студента{% endblock meta_title %}
{% block title %}Редагувати студента{% endblock title %}

Meta title puts meta text and title brings to page H2 text. I'd like to change the text in this blocks according to my views (if i enter createview so text will be changed to some, if another - template changes to another text)
I've tried to check it by ifequal or if request.path == url
but code has no effect.
How to check View that uses template in current time and change blocks' text in template for this view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send different context to the same template from the views.

Suppose you have two urls (/test1/ and /test2/) which use the same template, the different views associated with the urls can send different context objects to the same template in order to change the content.

So in your case you could edit the template as follows -

```
{% block meta_title %}{{some_variable}}{% endblock meta_title %} 
{% block title %}{{some_other_variable}}{% endblock title %}
```

Here you could send different values of the variables in the context object.

For example -

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import FormView, TemplateView
from  .forms import TestForm

class TestView1(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'test2.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TestView1, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Bansal'
        return context


class TestView2(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'test2.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TestView2, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Utkarsh'
        return context
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import RegisterView, TestView1, TestView2

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'', RegisterView.as_view()),
    url(r'^test1$', TestView1.as_view()),
    url(r'^test2$', TestView2.as_view()),
]
```

test2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
{{ title }}
</body>
</html>
```

Here note that both the template views use the same template - test2.html, the only difference is that different context values are passed from different views.

So when we open test1/ we see Bansal and on test2/ we see Utkarsh

Comment: how to use this on cbv side?

Comment: Should I add a working example? You basically need to override the get_context_data method in the CBV.

Comment: yes, please. I read now ccbv site and don't get: how tu put those var in context